# Moving a vector layer 20m to the west on QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, geometry, features, vector-layer

I have a vector layer of power lines for an area, the shapefile that I was given is actually around 20m to the west of where I know the power lines are actually supposed to be, as they are supposed to coincide with the main road and they do not. Is there an easy way to move this vector layer slightly to the east? I am using QGIS.

Comment: Welcome to gis.stackexchange! Please note that a good question on this site is expected to show some degree of research on your part, i.e. what you have tried and - if applicable - code so far. For more info, you can check our [faq].

Comment: see ParallelOffset https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ParallelOffset/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't need to work with great precision, you may use the **Move Feature(s)** tool, which allows moving the selected features:

[image]

You will find it in the main QGIS window.

Instead, if you need to work with more precision, you should edit your question by adding more information about the issue.

Comment: Thank you! This worked perfectly, I was trying it before but couldn't work out why it was not working, turns out I didn't have the lines saved correctly.

Comment: @LydiaKatsis I'm glad it worked. The tool is very useful for this kind of edits.